# Bathroom toilet install - path of least resistance

Tags: plumbing, basement, toilet, sewer

I want to install a toilet in my ugly old basement and am apprehensive about how to actually do it. 
Here's what I have:
[image]
...and here's how my house is plumbed:
[image]

So I'm trying to put a toilet on this line somewhere within the blue box on the diagram above. Is this advisable? I want to minimize or remove altogether any need to break into or cut any concrete. Wouldn't mind a solution involving a small platform or putting the toilet right next to this blue box area.

Comment: Breaking into concrete is not so bad, really. If the sizes in your illustration are accurate, you may not have the line capacity for a toilet, and you also appear to have a wet vent via the kitchen sink, which may not fly either. Presumably you are aware (or will be once ad robots look at your web activity) of "basement toilets" that pump uphill.

Answer (score 1):

Just " GOOGLE" a pump up toilet system and you will get many options. The one from Home Depot  will let you install a complete bathroom if desired and costs less than $700.00.

Comment: Down votes are for stupid answers, not for something that will actually work. I have one of these devices from home depot and it works great. Keep the down votes coming: I really don't care

Comment: I agree the pump toilets do work and are easier to install a better answer would explain that they actually grind the waste and pump it through a smaller line using 120 v and some water.+

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite correlate the photo with the drawing, but can't you dismantle the stack and re-jig it to take a new pipe and make it look more like the drawing? I.e. move the clean out point up a little and get a junction in there with bosses to take the waste water pipes?

Obviously it a little different here in the UK on what you can buy, but something like this...
[image: 4 boss double branch]

I'd definitely try to avoid breaking the concrete unless you have plans to spend money down there. It's easy to break something under the concrete and then you have to keep digging until you get to a good piece of pipe again...